# ngOnChanges() does not trigger button click

Tags: html, jquery, angular, typescript, addeventlistener

There's a button click event that I'd like to trigger and the function is placed inside `ngOnChanges()`. However, function is not able to triggered inside `ngOnChanges()` when the button is clicked. Did I miss anything?

Here's the sample code in ts file:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
    import { SafeResourceUrl, SafeHtml, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    declare var $: any;
    
    @Component({
        selector: 'sl-page',
        template: require('./sl-page.component.html')
    })
    export class PageComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
        constructor(
            private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
        ) { }
    
        ngOnInit() {
       
        }
    ngOnChanges() {
       
        $(function () {
            var btn= document.getElementsByClassName("buttonClass");
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
                btn[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                    /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
            to highlight the button that controls the panel */
                    this.classList.toggle("active");

                    /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
                    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                        panel.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        panel.style.display = "block";
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

And the html code for the button would be:

```
<div class="buttonBlock" tabindex="0">
    <button class="buttonClass" type="button">{{"Button"}}</button>
    <div class="textClass">this is the text when button is expanded</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in ngOnChanges(), did you try the block inside ngOnInit()

Comment: trying to trigger event inside ngOnChanges may cause infinite loop and seems antipattern. Also from your code it seems that you are activating an event listener, not triggering an event.

Comment: @GaneshBabu I tried inside the ngOnInit() as well but it doesn't trigger either

Answer (score -1):

try to change your ngOnChange methode like this :

```js
ngOnChanges() {
            var btn= document.getElementsByClassName("buttonClass");

            for (let button of btn) {
                button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
            to highlight the button that controls the panel */
                    this.classList.toggle("active");

                    /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
                    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                    //ternaire expression instead of if, just a proposition
                    panel.style.display = panel.style.display === "block" ? "none" ? "block"
                });
            }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( I tried to use debugger and when the button is clicked, the debugger does not stop on the code in ngOnChanges